# Varying performance with M1 MacBook Pro 512GB SSD

Tags: macos, ssd, performance, apple-silicon

As I look around the web, I see the M1 MacBook Pro with `512GB` SSD seems to attain `2800`-`2900`MBps read/write speeds in BlackMagic disk speed test.

On my machine, after a number of days and trials, I only see `2350`MBps for write.

TRIM is enabled, and `iostat` shows the machine is idle (and has been in evenings for a number of days), have run Diskutil etc.

I understand different size/model SSD will exhibit diff performance, but I'm directly wondering about why my 512GB SSD seems so far behind the pack.

Any ideas? Is this level of variance normal?

FWIW, my CPU type benchmarks are matching the pack.

Comment: FWIW, My M1 MacBook Pro 512 GB SSD is pretty consistently managing 2800-2900 MBps writes, and 2800ish reads - the reads vary, sometimes dropping to 2400 (using Blackmagic's Disk Speed Test version 3.2).

Comment: @negacao yep, I'm on same version 3.2 - can't seem to get over 2490 or so. Really weird.

Comment: Weird - what's your revision? Mine is 1161.40. (System Info -> NVMExpress).

Comment: @negacao yep same!   Model: APPLE SSD AP0512Q
  Revision: 1161.40. - its weird as Spotlight/FileVault etc is done. Called Apple they are happy to replace it.

Comment: Nuts.. better luck next with the next one then. :)

Comment: Got a new one and the performance is as expected... weird but exchange fixed it